# tsql join not pulling correct rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, report

I've been banging my head off the wall trying to solve this one and I'm at a road block, hoping someone can help.

I have two tables service_calls and service_code_description.

service_calls contains the service_codes, for each service call, both service_code_reported and service_code_actual.
Both of those line up to the service_code and description in the service_code_description table.

Here is where my problem is, I can only pull one description, not both.
Below is a sample of of my code I am using in SQL Report Builder.

```
    SELECT SC.[system_code]
      ,SC.[node_id]
      ,SC.[service_call_num]
      ,SC.[subs_acct_num]
      ,SC.[drop_address]
      ,SC.[city_code]
      ,SC.[province_code]
      ,SC.[head_end]
      ,(cast(SC.[service_code_reported] as varchar(4)) +char(10)+ d.service_code_description) [service_code_reported]
      ,(cast(SC.[service_code_actual1] as varchar(4)) +char(10)+ d.service_code_description) [service_code_actual1]
      ,SC.[service_code_actual2]
      ,SC.[service_code_actual3]
      ,SC.[service_code_actual4]
      ,SC.[completed_date]
      ,SC.[startdate]
      ,SC.[enddate]
  FROM
    [SC_Data] SC
INNER JOIN [lkup_Service_Code_Definition] d
ON 
    sc.system_code = d.system_code
WHERE
    year(startdate)=@year
and
    month(startdate)=@month
and
    node_id=@node_id
```

It outputs the following.

[image: sample_output]

What it Should output is
service code reported
004 Full Outage-All Services

service code actual 1
131 Cancelled Call-After Truck Roll

If anyone has any tips in the right direction I'd be very great full for the feedback.

Comment: please show us the sample input data too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing anything else, it appears as though you're using the same service_code_description source (d.service_code_description) for both the reported and actual dynamic columns.  You're joining to the lkup_Service_Code_Definition set on sc.system_code = d.system_code, however in your reported/actual dynamic fields you are referencing service_code_reported and service_code_actual1 values (instead of system_code (s)).

I'd go out on a limb at venture to guess that you will need to join to the lkup_Service_Code_Definition twice - once for the reported code and once for the actual (though this assumes the values in the service_code_reported and service_code_actual1 fields should map to that set's system_code value), something like:

```
select ...
        ,(cast(SC.[service_code_reported] as varchar(4)) +char(10)+ rd.service_code_description) [service_code_reported]
      ,(cast(SC.[service_code_actual1] as varchar(4)) +char(10)+ ad.service_code_description) [service_code_actual1]
       ....
from SC_Data sc
join lkup_Service_Code_Definition rd
on sc.service_code_reported = rd.system_code
join lkup_Service_Code_Definition ad
on sc.service_code_actual1 = ad.system_code
where  ...
```

Comment: I don't know how I scrolled past this, exactly what I needed. Thanks very much!
I didn't think of doing it that way with just calling the code_description twice but as a different var.
awesome and appreciated! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work;

```
    SELECT SC.[system_code]
          ,SC.[node_id]
          ,SC.[service_call_num]
          ,SC.[subs_acct_num]
          ,SC.[drop_address]
          ,SC.[city_code]
          ,SC.[province_code]
          ,SC.[head_end]
          ,(cast(SC.[service_code_reported] as varchar(4)) +char(10)+ d.service_code_description) [service_code_reported]
          ,(cast(SC.[service_code_actual1] as varchar(4)) +char(10)+ e.service_code_description) [service_code_actual1]
          ,SC.[service_code_actual2]
          ,SC.[service_code_actual3]
          ,SC.[service_code_actual4]
          ,SC.[completed_date]
          ,SC.[startdate]
          ,SC.[enddate]
      FROM
        [SC_Data] SC, [lkup_Service_Code_Definition] d,[lkup_Service_Code_Definition] e    
  WHERE
    d.system_code = SC.service_code_reported
    and 
    e.system_code = SC.service_code_actual1
    and
        year(startdate)=@year
    and
        month(startdate)=@month
    and
        node_id=@node_id
```

Comment: Awesome, that was just about it. I never thought of doing it that way.
I modified it a bit to be inner joins and just defining the serice_code_description as new variables.
Thanks very much for the push in the right direction. Greatly appreciated!